# Example/Tutorial for using Jersey InMemoryTestContainerFactory

Tags: jersey

Could someone please point me to an example JUnit test that uses `InMemoryTestContainerFactory`, from `jersey-test-framework-inmemory`, making a call to a dummy resource?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-inmemory/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/test/framework/impl/container/inmemory/testpackage/InMemoryPackageTest.java?rev=5700

Comment: I am getting a compilation error. It is unable to find the inmemorytestcontainerfactory class. Do you know which jar has it? I have jersey-test-external and jersey-test-core jars in my classpath.

Comment: com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework:jersey-test-framework-inmemory, see http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jersey-test-framework-inmemory%22